# file logger loglevel definition for my packages

Tags: spring-boot, logging, slf4j, application.properties

I am developing a spring boot application (v2.3.5)
I use logging with slf4j annotation:

```
package org.harri.operator;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class RequestOperator
{
....
public void myFunction()
{
   log.debug("Hello debug log");
}
....
}
```

I do configure logging in the application.properties file like so:

```
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.harri=DEBUG

logging.file.name=server.log
logging.pattern.rolling-file-name=server-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
logging.file.max-size=10MB
logging.file.total-size-cap=1000MB
logging.file.max-history=30
```

The logging "Hello debug log" appears on console but not in the log file.
What is wrong with my configuration? There must be something I generally misunderstand.

Thanks in advance
Harri E